# Easiest way to import MySQL database in nodejs for integration testing

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm

I have an web app built with nodejs and I want to do some integration testing of my API that will involve hitting a live database.

Is there any easy way to load & execute an SQL dump file to pre-populate the database before running my tests?

Answer (score 2):

You could group your sql queries for restoring your databases in any teardown or tearup events  when needed.

you might want to use any kind of flag before running your tests that needs a clean "data structure"

Answer (score 1):

To load the dump, in a terminal:

```
mysql -u youruser -p yourdatabasename < /path/to/your/dump_file.sql
```

type in the password.

If you want to create the dump, in a terminal:

```
mysqldump -u youruser -p yourdatabasename > /path/to/your/dump_file.sql
```

Comment: Yeah I was leaning towards running this command from within node. Through the course of my tests I'd need to run it several times to reset the database.

Comment: then you sould run bash commands from node.js, dig into that: check out this link  http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs

Comment: don't know why your tests should reset the db, why not creating tables as needed by the scripts?

Comment: It's always a good idea to eliminate potential side effects when testing components. Resetting a test database before testing a component will eliminate potential side effects of other tests that are created later that might modify the data in the database as part of the testing process.

Comment: can you execute your tests from a terminal?

Comment: yeah busterjs allows you to execute all of your tests from terminal

Comment: then execute a test, reload the db, execute another test, reload the db. always from the terminal